# SQL query with Like operator with Leading Wildcards

Tags: index, sql-server-2016, optimization, like, string-searching

I have a query as follows:

```
select top (30000) * from table1 where licenseplate like '%as43bv%'
```

I have an index on `licenseplate` but the query will not hit the index due to leading wildcard.

Since the column queries license plate numbers full text search wont come to any benefit we are searching on some letter or number rather than words

The above query fetches millions of rows and brings the CPU usage around 100%.

Is there any efficient way to rewrite the query and make use of the indexes.

Comment: Sorry using order by here but did not mention. My searches are based on either numbers or letters hence i guess full text will be of no benefit. For example '%a%' or '%2%' as i want to fetch plates that has letter 'a' or numbers '12'

Comment: Aaron Bertrand had a pretty clever way to make this work. There are obviously some trade offs to make it work, but it works. (And he literally mentions the license plate example)  https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-indexes/seek-leading-wildcard-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

What first comes to mind, is that if you are searching for some symbols inside the `licenseplate` that will always start, for example at 4th symbol (example data `123as43bvxxx` ), and it will be always be fixed, you can consider adding computed persisted column to your table

```
alter table [table1]
add LicenseplateComputed as substring(licenseplate,4,50) persisted
```

And then create nonclustered index on your newly added computed column "LicenseplateComputed"

After this you will be able to query your table

```
select top (30000) * from table1 where LicenseplateComputed like 'as43bv%'
```

and it will perform efficient Index Seek

Comment: the thing is that the searches are completely random for example if  a state has 6 digit plate the search can start with any letters or numbers '%a%' or '%2%'

Comment: @SQL_NoExpert then probably search logic must be changed, first letters of license must be supplied instead of trying to search some characters that are in the middle of the column..  sometime we have to zoom out and change approach